# Get all entries having a value from List[Option] in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

Is it possible to get all entries of a `List[Option[T]]` having a value?

Example:

```
val list = List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2))
list.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
```

result:

```
 List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Is there a method to do it in one step? It's a common case, isn't it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Note that

```
 list.flatten
```

Will do just as well.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use `collect` for that:

```
list.collect { case Some(x) => x }
```

`collect` takes a `PartialFunction[A,B]` and applies this function to all the elements on which it is defined and discards the rest.

**edit**:

As gpampara correctly mentioned, for this case `flatten` will be sufficient. `collect` would be the right tool if there were additional constraints and/or transforming.

Comment: Thanks. You can rely on Scala that there is always a more elegant way ;-)

Comment: An even more elegant way is simply: `list.flatten`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
list.flatMap( x => x)

scala> val a = List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2))
a: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(1), None, Some(2))

scala> a.flatMap(x => x)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

For explanation of how/why this works, you might check out this article: http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/

Comment: Yes, it works. But I don't understand why. According to the docs `flatMap` must return `Option`.

Comment: http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/ here is good explanation

Comment: My mistake was to look at `flatMap` on the `Option` class, but of course I had to look at `List.flatMap`.